# HTML header with multiple rows

Tags: css, html, styles

[image]

I want to create a header for a website that looks like the one in the image above.

- Div1 is top left, has fixed size (it's a logo)
- Div2 and Div3 are right of Div1
- Div4 is center right (top right is also acceptable)

Is such a layout possible with divs? Should I use a table instead?

Comment: Your image is not clear, can you please upload a better image. Yes, any kind of layout is possible with `divs` and CSS.

Comment: You shouldn't use tables, as this isn't tabular data.  You should have a go at making this with `divs`, and then post the HTML and CSS if it isn't working so that people can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I created an example using divs only

```css
#bigbox {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

#bigbox div {
  float: left;
}

#logobox {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#column2 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: green;
}

.row {
  height: 50%;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#rightContent {
  float: right !important;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigbox">
  <div id="logobox"></div>
  <div id="column2">
    <div class="row">1</div>
    <div class="row">2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightContent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap we can achieve this like below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">a</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">b</div>
</div>
```